# jQuery DOMNodeInserted: Find specific element

Tags: jquery, mutation-events

I would like to know how I can listen to the DOM when a SPECIFIC element is added, and then act upon it.

After the DOM s loaded initially, there is a div(.myElement) that is loaded long afterwards:

```
<div class="container">.
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <div class="myElement"></div>
</div>

 $("div.container").bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
        alert("div.myElement has just been appended");
    });
```

Now the moment the element:

```
<div class="myElement"></div>
```

is added to the parent div(container), i want to run a function.
How do i do that?

Thank you

Comment: How is your element loaded ?

Comment: it is actually a google map with map markers/pins on it. the moment you click a pin, there is an infobox that is added. Basically I want to listen for when that infobox is added to the DOM, and I cannot find the ID for the pin/map marker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. [DOmNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) has been removed and there's no alternative.

Solutions to provide a similar behavior are

- pulling, ie testing with `setInterval` for additions. That would degrade performances.
- changing the code inserting the element.

Comment: so you mean DOMNodeinserted is depreciated? How would I go about your suggestions then? Example?

Comment: also, the code being inserted is via a google maps plugin, so that would be difficult to impossible(for me at least)

Comment: I really don't suggest to pull, so the solution is in ensuring a callback is called by the Map API when the element is loaded. I don't know the Map API enough so I'd suggest you change the question to make it be about this point (with relevant code), if you don't find the answer in Google's API documentation.